# How to not display information if it exists in one of two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json, api

The situation is I have two arrays that is collecting JSON data via the API :

```
$players  = getAPI("http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx/players.json?apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
$recents  = getAPI("xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx/recent.json?apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
```

The method is getting the contents and decoding the JSON into an array.
For the players array we have this data in an array:

$players

```
[
  {
    "id": "76561198033377272",
    "name": "PitMonk",
    "position": {
      "x": -339,
      "y": 26,
      "z": 191
    },
    "rotation": 128,
    "time": 418310,
    "ip": "",
    "inventory": {
      "main": [],
      "belt": [
        {
          "name": "rock",
          "amount": 1,
          "blueprint": false,
          "condition": 100
        },
        {
          "name": "torch",
          "amount": 1,
          "blueprint": false,
          "condition": 100
        }
      ],
      "wear": []
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "76561198088638439",
    "name": "Pippa",
    "position": {
      "x": -337,
      "y": 25,
      "z": 177
    },
    "rotation": 73,
    "time": 419136,
    "ip": "",
    "inventory": {
      "main": [
        {
          "name": "arrow.wooden",
          "amount": 12,
          "blueprint": false
        },
        {
          "name": "bow.hunting",
          "amount": 1,
          "blueprint": false,
          "condition": 93
        },
        {
          "name": "blueprint_fragment",
          "amount": 25,
          "blueprint": false
        },
        {
          "name": "metal.fragments",
          "amount": 1366,
          "blueprint": false
        },
        {
          "name": "metal.refined",
          "amount": 48,
          "blueprint": false
        },
        {
          "name": "charcoal",
          "amount": 1120,
          "blueprint": false
        },
        {
          "name": "lowgradefuel",
          "amount": 738,
          "blueprint": false
        }
      ],
      "belt": [
        {
          "name": "rock",
          "amount": 1,
          "blueprint": false,
          "condition": 100
        },
        {
          "name": "torch",
          "amount": 1,
          "blueprint": false,
          "condition": 100
        },
        {
          "name": "pickaxe",
          "amount": 1,
          "blueprint": false,
          "condition": 76
        },
        {
          "name": "pickaxe",
          "amount": 1,
          "blueprint": false,
          "condition": 17
        },
        {
          "name": "pickaxe",
          "amount": 1,
          "blueprint": false,
          "condition": 100
        },
        {
          "name": "pickaxe",
          "amount": 1,
          "blueprint": false,
          "condition": 100
        }
      ],
      "wear": [
        {
          "name": "burlap.shirt",
          "amount": 1,
          "blueprint": false
        },
        {
          "name": "attire.hide.skirt",
          "amount": 1,
          "blueprint": false
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

$recents

```
[
  {
    "id": "76561198039206786",
    "name": "JakeGroves"
  },
  {
    "id": "76561198088638439",
    "name": "Pippa"
  },
  {
    "id": "76561198033377272",
    "name": "PitMonk"
  },
  {
    "id": "76561198146864439",
    "name": "YepWellDone"
  },
  {
    "id": "76561198164836207",
    "name": "Baz"
  },
  {
    "id": "76561198076406281",
    "name": "xwalnutx"
  },
  {
    "id": "76561197985716090",
    "name": "Darkflame134"
  },
  {
    "id": "76561198263423842",
    "name": "XitaikiznerX"
  },
  {
    "id": "76561198129952244",
    "name": "NatanGamer"
  },
  {
    "id": "76561198071842055",
    "name": "Baha Bey"
  }
]
```

As you can see the players is the people connected, and recents is the total list of people who have connected recently.

I have attempted this:

```
 foreach ($players as $player) {
       echo $players->name;
    }
    echo "</br></br>";
    foreach ($recent as $rec) {
      if ($rec->name != $player->name) {
       echo $rec->name . "</br>";
     }
    }
```

and it produces the result:

```
PitMonk Pippa

JakeGroves
PitMonk
YepWellDone
Baz
xwalnutx
Darkflame134
XitaikiznerX
NatanGamer
Baha Bey
```

So it is only ignoring 'pippa', I am not sure if it is possible to interact with two arrays as such for unique values?

Comment: Your algorithm seems to be OK, what is the problem exactly ? The output seems to be weird, I don't see how it can display two players names on the same line since you echo a br after each name. How 'PitMonk Pippa
' can be displayed on the same line ?

Comment: And maybe you should match users on ids, it's cleaner than comparing names.

Comment: @OlivierH yaa im using names so i can tell who it is right now and well if you see in the first line Pitmonk and Pippa are in $players array and they are both in $recents array, but what i am trying to do is loop through the $recents array and ignore any entries that exist in $players array

Comment: What is the `$users` array ? you don't use `$players` at all in your code.

Comment: shoot yer i wrote it down wrong $users = $players .... i have done this code and i think it is working ...     `foreach ($recent as $rec) {
      foreach ($users as $user) {
        if ($user->name == $rec->name) {
          break;
        }
      }
      if ($user->name != $rec->name) {
        echo $rec->name;
      }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You are interested in listing all names out of `$users` which don't exist in `$players` **or** `$recents`, right?

Assuming you are only interested in the name:

```
// First, let's get a new array with all names from both arrays (can contain dups)
$pcNames = array_map($players + $recents, function($playerObject) {
    return $playerObject->name;
});

// Next, let's remove all dups
$pcNames = array_unique($pcNames);

// === At this point you have an array with all names from `$players` and `$recents` ===
// === You may do something else with those, but I'll now create another array with  ===
// === all users not in the players/recents lists.                                   ===

// Now let's also get a list of names of users in the `$users` variable
$userNames = array_map($users, function($playerObject) {
    return $playerObject->name;
});

// And finally let's get all names which are not in players or recents
$diffNames = array_diff($userNames, $pcNames);

// Let's output those to see whether it worked
var_dump($diffNames);
```

Of course there are other ways depending on your use case. We could for example extract the names of all three arrays and then just use `array_diff` with 3 arguments (but then you don't have the `$pcArray` side product), or if you actually want to compare IDs but print names, we would have to change all the inline functions to extract ID instead of name and further down reference the users array to get the actual name, etc.

Comment: Why using an intermediate array `$userNames` ? It could be really memory consuming if his users data is huge. It would be more efficient to only loop on `$users` array and to feed another array when `$user->name` is not found in `$pcNames`;

Comment: You are right that it may be more performant. Feel free to post your idea in an answer. My answer tries to break it down into steps using array functions which describe what they are doing so the "flow" of the data is made clearer.